# How to obtain Mel Filterbank?

Tags: speech-recognition, audio-processing, mfcc

What is the logic behind the calculation of Mel filterbank? Is there any good example for it ? I could not find any good example on internet.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 6):

You can find a really nice tutorial on how to obtain Mel filter banks [here](https://haythamfayek.com/2016/04/21/speech-processing-for-machine-learning.html).

In general, we use Mel filter banks for two main reasons.

- The Mel scale aim to mimic non-linear human ear perception of sound. Human ears are more discriminative at lower frequencies and less discriminative at higher frequencies. Mel filter banks do exactly that by giving a better resolution at low frequencies and less at high.
- Triangular filter banks help to capture the energy at each critical frequency band and roughly approximates the spectrum shape. This also helps to smooth the harmonic structure.

[Filter bank on a Mel scale](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7l7SX.jpg)